# Upside down PHP array values?

Tags: php, arrays

I have array echo this: `(2 5 7 13 19 22 23 37 41 41 64 74 85 96 139);`
But I need this echo: `(139 96 85 74 64 41 41 37 23 22 19 13 7 5 2);`
I can't find, how to upside down echo value?

```
$num= array(7,13,85,64,2,41,22,96,139,37,41,19,74,23,5);
$max= max($num);
$a= count($num);
sort($num);

for ($x=0; $x < $a; $x++) {
        echo $num[$x]. " ";
}
```

output: `2 5 7 13 19 22 23 37 41 41 64 74 85 96 139`

Comment: for ( $x=($a-1); $x >= 0; $x—)

Comment: Start from the final index and loop backwards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace `sort($num);` with `rsort($num);`.

[`sort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) sorts from *low to high*.

[`rsort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rsort.php) sorts from *high to low*.

Answer (score 0):

use array rsort()

```
$output=rsort($num);
```

Answer (score 0):

If array is **already sorted**, then use [`array_reverse`](http://php.net/array_reverse). It is more performant than sorting array in descending order.

```
$reversedOrderArray = array_reverse($yourArray);
```

Comment: `$num[$x]` is not __array__, `$num` is.

Comment: Oh yeah, I have found it, it's working! Thanks dude. :)